# "The Romans' Book" in Ramba"n

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, history, books-generally, bechukosai, rome

The [commentary of *Ramba"n* on Vayikra 26](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=3&perek=26&mefaresh=ramban):16 explains a [large swath of *parashas B'chukosai*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechukotai#Blessings_and_curses) as an allegory to the two *[batei Mikdash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Temple_in_Jerusalem)* and the corresponding exiles. Included therein, he elaborates on the warring and exiling protocols of the Roman Empire, citing as corroborative proof "The Romans' book".

> וכן כתוב בספר הרומיים...

Is there a specific book to which he is referring or is it simply pointing the skeptical reader to check the original documentation of the Romans' own if he needs more proof to *Ramba"n*'s contention?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Torah periodical [ישורון for Kislev 5767](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46424&pgnum=37), in an article on "Derashat haRamban - Torat Hashem Temimah", on page 38-9 (and specifically in footnote 14) Rav Yaakov Yehuda Zilberlicht discusses what Ramban is referring to by ספר הרומאים (The Book of the Romans). Possibilities that he raises:

- It is obvious that Ramban is referring to a Roman history book, the question is: which one?
- הגר"י ספרקה (Rav Y. Spraka?) in his commentary "Chazon haGeulah on Sefer haGeula) says that this is referring to [Josephus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus). Especially because it records a parallel event there. Also Rav Chadah in his commentary on Ramban.
- General Roman history books (and not Josephus) - since Ramban makes specific reference to Josephus in a different place, if he wanted to refer to it by name, he would have. Also, there are many other places in Ramban where he refers to "Sifrei X" - "the books of X", X being the name of other nation (Casdeans, Egyptions, Umat Tzava, etc), so there is precedent for Ramban referring to history books of some non-Jewish nation in this way.