# What is the stance on reading and writing non-Jewish literature?

Tags: halacha, books-generally

So, I'm guessing that secular study books (e.g. Biology, Math, etc) are fine and I've heard that reading something like Fantasy is not. What genres of literature are allowed and not allowed to be read or written?

And as YEZ has suggested below, please mention how it's viewed (poorly, fine, etc).

Comment: "allowed" implies you are asking about being strictly forbidden or permitted, which may be very limited in scope.  If you are also interested in which are looked down upon or not recommended, you may want to reword your question.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31614 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25772 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/21764 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33780 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25845 .  Tangentially related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30105 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7473 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16981 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9936

Comment: Some would hold that science books aren't ok either...  This question could be generalized to secular culture in general. As such, related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25772/reading-foreign-literature-perspectives-and-experiences/37178